# vue js how "process.env" variables in index.html

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

I am trying to use env variables in my html markup to change env variables according to whether I am in production or development mode .. So for context using mixpanel I have two projects one for development and one for production with different api keys. how would I use webpack to do this, accessing my process.env.VUE_APP_MIXPANEL env variable in my html ?

Comment: To answer this it is important to know how you are you serving your Vue project

Comment: @Imre_G I am using vue ui, and then running this command `vue-cli-service serve --open` . So you cannot use process.env in html script tags if I am not mistaken

Comment: I think you are correct. Maybe you can check this out: https://github.com/Glovo/vue-multianalytics#mixpanel

Comment: @Imre_G thank you ..

Answer (score 21):

If you are using the default Webpack template you can access the .env variables in index.html using this syntax (for example):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= VUE_APP_TITLE %></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

Obviously you need to have a variable like this

```
VUE_APP_TITLE=My title
```

in your .env file

Comment: I tried but not working.

Comment: The default vue-webpack config seems to only utilize `/.env` properties that start with the string, "VUE_APP_".

Answer (score 4):

With Google reCAPTCHA, I included my script like this:

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=<%= process.env.VUE_APP_RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY %>"></script>
```

The env var is `VUE_RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY`. It may be present in `.env` file.

Comment: I tried but not working.

Comment: does this work for variables in `.env.production`?

Comment: Yes, .env.production is only a way to define env var for that specific environment. More info: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#what-other-env-files-can-be-used

Answer (score 3):

**When using `.env` in index.html as HTML you can use this:**

```HTML
<link
  rel="icon"
  type="image/ico"
  href="<%= process.env.FAVICON_ICO_URL %>"
/>
```

or this:

```HTML
<title><%= process.env.SITE_TITLE %></title>
```

**When using `.env` variables injected into  tags of index.html you need to use them as a string like this:**

```HTML
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>
  (function (w, d, s, l, i) {
    w[l] = w[l] || [];
    w[l].push({ 'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(), event: 'gtm.js' });
    var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
      j = d.createElement(s),
      dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : '';
    j.async = true;
    j.src = 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl;
    f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
  })(
    window,
    document,
    'script',
    'dataLayer',
    '<%= process.env.GTM_CONTAINER_ID %>'
  );
</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, I then came across this package that allows me you to add google analytics to your vue projects .. https://github.com/MatteoGabriele/vue-analytics or https://github.com/Glovo/vue-multianalytics if you also want to add other tracking providers .